# Why does a substituted formula work for lm and oneway.test, but not aov?

Tags: r, formula, substitution

```
 example <- data.frame(
   var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
   class = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4))
 )
 example$class <- as.factor(example$class)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987367/substitute-in-r-together-with-anova) provides a fix for using substitute and as.name to create a formula for `aov`, but I don't understand why the formula works for `oneway.test` and `lm`. Can someone explain?

```
 fm <- substitute(i ~ class, list(i = as.name('var1')))
 oneway.test(fm, example)

    One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  var1 and class
F = 19.2, num df = 1, denom df = 6, p-value = 0.004659

 lm(fm, example)

Call:
lm(formula = fm, data = example)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       class2  
        2.5          4.0  

 aov(fm, example)
Error in terms.default(formula, "Error", data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `substitute` is returning an unevaluated call, not a formula. Compare

```
class(substitute(a~b))
# [1] "call"
class(a~b)
# [1] "formula"
```

If you evaluate it (as was done in the other answer), both will work

```
fm <- eval(substitute(i ~ class, list(i = as.name('var1'))))
oneway.test(fm, example)
aov(fm, example)
```

The error message you were getting was from the `terms` function which is called by `aov()`. This function needs to operate on a formula, not a call. This is basically what was happening

```
# ok
terms(a~b)

# doesn't work
unf <- quote(a~b)  #same as substitute(a~b)
terms(unf)
# Error in terms.default(unf) : no terms component nor attribute

# ok
terms(eval(unf))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of the difference is that `fm` is actually a `call` not a `formula` and apparently some functions do the conversion while others do not.

If you do:

```
fm <- as.formula(fm)
```

Then the call to `aov` will work.